# Can't use liveData or viewModelScope.launch

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use these two builders for coroutines in my app, but in my ViewModel I can't import them or they do not pop up.

These are my dependencies:

```
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc02"

   implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2'
```

and in my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(): ViewModel() {

init{

  viewModelScope ----> does not work , marked in red
  val data = liveData {} ----> does not work, marked in red
}


}
```

I rebuilt, cleaned, and restarted with invalidating cache, but I can't use them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the ViewModel ktx lib:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx$lifecycle_version"
```

Available after AndroidX lifecycle v2.1.0

Comment: do I need to import coroutines:android or with just this coroutines are working for livedata ?

Comment: KTX is a supportive lib that works as an extension from the main lib, so, this is complementary, it doesn't work alone. To use the livedata you must add this:  "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$livedata_version"

Comment: You can get more details from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Answer (score 1):

for liveData:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$livedata_version"
```

for viewModelScope:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above additions to `build.gradle` with cache invalidation and rebuild still were not sufficient to resolve the issue for me (Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2). Only when I wrote `this.` I could choose `viewModelScope` from the pulldown, with automatic import insertion.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following dependencies in your Gradle module file:**

I had the same problem but I solved by adding the following dependencies.

```
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    def arch_version = "2.2.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycle utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version")

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version")

    // Annotation processor
    kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
```